# C calling functions -

Tags: c, function, struct

I have a simple code with functions declared ( i assume correctly) but i get no prompting for the scanf(). I have functions with void return, and passing them by values. I need the function retrieve to prompr for the scanf so as to input the data.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Len 10

void retrieve(void);
void update(void);
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    float A[Len];
    float B[Len];
    float C[Len];

printf("Give 10 real numbers for each array, A and B.\n");
void retrieve();
void update();
//Print each newly created value from table C.
printf("\nArray C has now:\n");
        for (i = 1; i <= Len; i++)
        {
            printf("Position: %d || Value: %.2lf\n",i,C[i]);
        }
}
void retrieve (void) // Get the values for array A and B.
{
        for (i = 1; i <= Len; i++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", &A[i]);
        }

        for (i = 1; i <= Len; i++)
        {
            scanf("%lf", &B[i]);
        }
}
void update (void) //Add the items from array A and B into C.
{
    for (i = 1; i <= Len; i++)
        {
            C[i]=A[i]+B[i];
        }
}
```

Comment: You are not passing arrays to the functions.

Comment: I don't think this even compiles ?

Comment: it complied initially.

Answer (score 3):

Note that when you think you are calling your functions here:

```
void retrieve();
void update();
```

you are actually just redeclaring prototypes. Change this to:

```
retrieve();
update();
```

in order to actually call these functions.

You also need to either make your arrays global or pass them as parameters to your functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your code

- you are not passing the arrays A,B,C to the retreive/update functions
- you are indexing them wrong. you must start with i=0, not 1.
- you are overriding `update()`/`retreive()` in the main function. You must just invoke them (so leave out the `void`) before it.

Here is a working example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define Len 10

static void retrieve (float* A, float* B);
static void update (const float* A, const float* B, float* C);
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    float A[Len];
    float B[Len];
    float C[Len];

    printf("Give 10 real numbers for each array, A and B.\n");
    retrieve(A, B);
    update(A, B ,C);
    //Print each newly created value from table C.
    printf("\nArray C has now:\n");
    for (i = 1; i <= Len; i++)
    {
            printf("Position: %d || Value: %.2lf\n",i,C[i]);
    }
}

static void retrieve (float* A, float* B) // Get the values for array A and B.
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Len; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &A[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < Len; i++)
    {
        scanf("%lf", &B[i]);
    }
}

static void update (const float* A, const float* B, float* C) //Add the items from array A and B into C.
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < Len; i++)
    {
        C[i]=A[i]+B[i];
    }
}
```